# Changing ExtJS Images

Tags: extjs, theming

I created a theme which extends the ext-theme-classic, but I want to use the neptune-theme images for tools, sliders etc.
I copied the neptune-theme images folder into my resources folder and changed the

```
$relative-image-path-for-uis
```

to this directory, but it doesn't work.
Where's my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here might be the image file type.

Example: `ext-theme-classic` form images use `.gif` while `ext-theme-neptune` uses `.png`. So if you want to use neptune's form images, copy the images to your custom theme then find an image editor and change its file type from png to gif.

Or you need to override `Component.scss` (sass/var/) then set the following:

from:

```
$image-extension: 'gif' !default;
```

to:

```
$image-extension: 'png' !default;
```

*Note: I haven't actually tried the second option but I think it should work :)*

Comment: could I also use the global_css $image-extension to do that?

Comment: kindly try my second suggestion found on my updated answer :)